# How to make this second ListView displayed (visible) after selecting a row in the first ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I have to create a quiz engine application. I am using three LiveView controls to show:
    1. quiz information
    2. question information (based on the selected quiz on the first ListView)
    3. answers information (based on the selected question on the second ListView)

I have the following database design:

```
QuizContent Table: ID, QuizID, QuestionID, AnswerID, isCorrect
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description, isSent
Question Table: QuestionID, Question, QuestionOrder, AnswerExplanation
Answers Table: AnswerID, Answer
```

**What I want now is the following:** when the user (who is the Admin) comes to the Quiz Engine Page, he should only see the first ListView which is mainly about the Quiz Information. And when he selects one of the quizzes, the second ListView will be displayed with the Question information of that selected quiz. And when he selects one of the questions, the third ListView will be displayed with the answers information of that selected question.

**So how to do that?**

I know I should not post too much code or information, but I have to do it to make it clear:

```
<div align="center">
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="QuizID" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" >

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" ToolTip="Update"  runat="server" CommandName="Update" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                No data was returned.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/add24.png" ToolTip="Add"  runat="server" CommandName="Insert" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/clear24.png" ToolTip="Cancel"  runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </td>

                        <%--<td>
                            &nbsp;</td>--%>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete"  runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit"  runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="SelectButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/select.png" ToolTip="Select"  runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                            <%--<asp:Button ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />--%>
                        </td>
                        <%--<td>
                            <asp:Label ID="QuizIDLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("QuizID") %>' />
                        </td>--%>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <div ><table id="thetable" width="97%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; border:2px solid #003366; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color:#C6D7B5;">
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">...</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Title</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Description</th>
                            </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody><tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
                    </table></div>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <SelectedItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                        </td>
                        <%--<td>
                            <asp:Label ID="QuizIDLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("QuizID") %>' />
                        </td>--%>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </SelectedItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 

                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Quiz]" 
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Quiz] WHERE [QuizID] = @QuizID" 
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Quiz] ([Title], [Description]) VALUES (@Title, @Description)" 


                UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Quiz] SET [Title] = @Title, [Description] = @Description WHERE [QuizID] = @QuizID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuizID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuizID" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <%--Second ListView that will contain the content of the quiz--%>
    <div align="center">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
            DataKeyNames="QuestionID" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">

            <EditItemTemplate>

                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" ToolTip="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionIDLabel1" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
                    </td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionOrderTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerExplanationTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>

            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" 
                    style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/add24.png" ToolTip="Add" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/clear24.png" ToolTip="Cancel"  runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        &nbsp;</td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionOrderTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("QuestionOrder") %>'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerExplanationTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </InsertItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="SelectButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/select.png" ToolTip="Select" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                            <%--<asp:Button ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />--%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionOrderLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerExplanationLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div ><table id="thetable" width="97%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; border:2px solid #003366; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color:#C6D7B5;">
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">...</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Question</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Question Order</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Answer Explanation</th>
                            </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody><tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
                    </table></div>     
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionOrderLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerExplanationLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Question].* FROM [Question] INNER JOIN [QuizContent] ON [QuizContent].[QuizID] = @QuizID"

            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Question] WHERE [QuestionID] = @QuestionID" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Question] ([Question], [QuestionOrder], [AnswerExplanation]) VALUES (@Question, @QuestionOrder, @AnswerExplanation)" 


            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Question] SET [Question] = @Question, [QuestionOrder] = @QuestionOrder, [AnswerExplanation] = @AnswerExplanation WHERE [QuestionID] = @QuestionID">

                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Question" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionOrder" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerExplanation" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="QuizID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Question" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionOrder" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerExplanation" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="QuizID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <br /><br />

    <%--Third ListView that will contain the content of the quiz--%>
    <div align="center">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
            DataKeyNames="AnswerID" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">

            <EditItemTemplate>

                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" ToolTip="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AnswerID") %>' />
                    </td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Answer") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>

            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" 
                    style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/add24.png" ToolTip="Add" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/clear24.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        &nbsp;</td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Answer") %>'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </InsertItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AnswerID") %>' />
                    </td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Answer") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div ><table id="thetable" width="97%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; border:2px solid #003366; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color:#C6D7B5;">
                            <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">...</th>
                            <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Answer</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody><tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
                </table></div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Answer") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Answers].* FROM [Answers] INNER JOIN [QuizContent] ON [QuizContent].QuestionID = @QuestionID"

            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Answers] WHERE [AnswerID] = @AnswerID" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Answers] ([Answer]) VALUES (@Answer)" 


            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Answers] SET [Answer] = @Answer WHERE [AnswerID] = @AnswerID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Answer" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView2" Name="QuestionID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Answer" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView2" Name="QuestionID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**NOTE:**
I don't have any code-behind. And again the problem is as following: when I run the code, I will see the three ListView controls. It should show only one of them. And when the user selects one of the rows, the second ListView will be displayed and so on for the third ListView.

**UPDATE:**

I tried the following way but it did not work with me:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ListView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }
    protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView2.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the DataKey Like this

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="QuizID"  
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" DataKeyNames="ID" >
```

And make sure to get the ID in the SQLDataSource

then in the Itemcommand try this :

```
ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
 int ID = Convert.toInt32(ListView1.DataKeys[dataItem.DisplayIndex].Values[0]);
```

here is your ID now you can make the second listview visible and use this ID to Fill the second Listview

Hope I Helped

Comment: Actually, I did not get how to use ItemCommand to show the second ListView. It will be grateful if you can show me that

Comment: Open the web form and in the design view right click it then in the events (It Looks Like a lighting bolt) then you will find the ItemCommand in it just double click it and you will have the ItemCommand in the codebehind

Comment: Thanks, but my question was about how to use the ID in letting the second ListView to be displayed. Anyway, I will try to get it.

Comment: You Have The Quiz ID in the second SQLDataSource as a parameter you pass the ID to that parameter like this
SqlDataSources.SelectParameters.Add("parameterName", "parameterValue");

in Youe Case Try this
SqlDataSources.SelectParameters.Add("@QuizID", ID);
the ID in the DataKey

Try It and See What Will Happen

Comment: Is it possible to have two DataKeyNames in the ListView? I already defiend QuizID as a DatakeyNames, so what is the need of the ID that you added?

Comment: No it is the same ID (That is My fault), but sure you can have more than one DataKeyNames

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
first put the ID in the datakey in the first listview
then in the item command Get the ID of the selected row from the datakey
then you can make the second listview visible and fill it using this ID
and you can do the same to the last listview

Don't forget to make the second and last listview visible false so the won't see them unless he select row first in the first listview

Comment: Thanks for your help but since I am a new developer I did not get what you mean by your paragraph. Could you please elaborate more and provide me with a code snippet (if possible)?